# Apply parser n times vs on the first n characters (Haskell)

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am studying parsers in Haskell following definitions from [G. Hutton, E. Meijer - Monadic Parsing in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/pearl.pdf).

```hs
data Parser a = Parser { parseWith :: String -> [(a, String)] }

instance Functor Parser where
    fmap f (Parser p) = Parser $ \s -> [(f a, rest) | (a, rest) <- p s]

instance Applicative Parser where
    pure x = Parser $ \s -> [(x, s)]
    (Parser p1) <*> (Parser p2) = Parser $ \s -> [(f x, r2) | (f, r1) <- p1 s, (x, r2) <- p2 r1]

instance Monad Parser where
    return = pure
    p >>= f = Parser $ \s -> concatMap (\(x, r) -> parseWith (f x) r) $ parseWith p s

instance Alternative Parser where
    empty = failure
    p1 <|> p2 = Parser $ \s ->
        case parseWith p1 s of
        []  -> parseWith p2 s
        res -> res
```

Essentially I have a `(parsed :: a, remaining :: String)` context.

---

As a simple application, I defined the following ADT to parse:

```hs
data Arr = Arr Int [Int] -- len [values]
```

and a parser that can construct `Array` values from strings, e.g.:

```
"5|12345" -> Arr 5 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

---

First, in order to parse `n` such `Array` values (the string input contains `n` on the first position), e.g.:

```
"2 3|123 4|9876 2|55" -> [Arr 3 [1,2,3], Arr 4 [9,8,7,6]]
```

I can do the following:

```hs
arrayParse :: Parser Arr
arrayParse = do
    len <- digitParse
    vals <- exactly len digitParse
    return $ Arr len vals

nArraysParse :: Parser [Arr]
nArraysParse = do
    n <- digitParse
    exactly n arrayParse
```

where `exactly n p` constructs a new parser by applying `p` `n` times.

---

Next, I want to parse a different scheme.
Suppose the first character denotes the **length of the sub-string** defining the arrays, e.g.:

```
"9 3|123 4|9876 2|55" -> [Arr 3 [1,2,3], Arr 4 [9,8,7,6]]
```

Meaning that I have to apply `arrayParse` on the first `n` chars (excluding `|` and whitespace) to get the first 2 arrays:

```
3|123  -> 4 chars (excluding | and whitespace)
4|9876 -> 5 chars (excluding | and whitespace)
```

---

So, it's straightforward to **apply a parser `n` times**:

```hs
exactly :: Int -> Parser a -> Parser [a]
exactly 0 _ = pure []
exactly n p = do
    v  <- p               -- apply parser p once
    v' <- exactly (n-1) p -- apply parser p n-1 times
    return (v:v')
```

but how can I express the intent of **applying a parser on the first `n` characters**?

My initial approach was something like this:

```hs
foo :: Parser [Arr]
foo = do
   n <- digitParse
   substring <- consume n
   -- what to do with substring?
   -- can I apply arrayParse on it?
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: Monadic parsers abstract out the input, so it’s not trivial to apply them to a string that you obtained inside the monad. It might be possible to extend the parser with a function which accesses the internals of the monad and allows you to do this. It would probably look something like `innerParse :: Parser a -> String -> a`, and would work by applying `parseWith` and then lifting into the outer monad.

Comment: Also, side note: make sure you account for spaces when parsing the nested-array formats that you defined as including spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [@jlwoodwa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15326544/jlwoodwa)'s advice, I managed to achieve the following:

```hs
innerParse :: Parser a -> String -> Parser a
innerParse p s = case parseWith p s of
    [(arr, "")] -> return arr
    _ -> failure

substringParse :: Parser [Arr]
substringParse = do
    n <- digitParse
    substring <- consume n
    innerParse (zeroOrMore arrayParse) substring
```

which works for my use-case.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the only way you can do it.

Comment: The only thing I would change would be to move the `zeroOrMore` call from inside `innerParse` to `substringParse`. After all, it would be completely reasonable for some other part of your parser to want to demand a `oneOrMore`, or some other variable-length format that isn't even directly a list.

Comment: Right, valid point; edited it now, thanks!